# What are good Relative Humidity and Temperature settings on an MHRV and are the settings related?

Tags: hvac, ventilation, humidity, temperature

I need to configure the threshold Relative Humidity and Temperature settings on an whole house MHRV system.

The way the system works is that if the RH threshold is exceeded the system increases the fan speed to supply outside air into the house and extract more old air out of the house.

If the temperature threshold is exceeded and the air outside is colder than the inside temperature then it bypasses the heat exchanger to supply the air into the house without pre-warming. It also bypasses the heat exchanger if the inside temperature is lower than the threshold and the external temperature is higher than the internal temperature.

Are the two settings related, does my choice of target temperature affect what I should choose for RH?

Does the climate I am in (southern UK if it helps) and time of year affect what I should choose, how does it affect it?

Is there anything else I should consider when selecting the settings?